# Is there any activation function that can make batch normalization obsolete?

Tags: machine-learning

While learning batch normalization, I was thinking why can't we solve the "gradient scale problem" by using an appropriate activation function ?

Like can't we delay and scale the activation function instead of scaling the whole dataset and ensure that the variance is preserve through it ?

Comment: I guess you are a bit wrong, you are talking about data normalization rather than batch normalization, the former is a pre-processing step.

Comment: I was talking about normalising at each layer "automatically" or normalizing at the beginning and keep data's shape through layers.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe sounds a lot like Scaled-Exponential Linear Units (SELUs), that are the core of [Self-Normalizing Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6698-self-normalizing-neural-networks.pdf), which where presented at NIPS 2017.

A short summary from [here](http://shaofanlai.com/post/29) is that:

> If the mean and variance of the input is in certain range, then the mean and variance of the output should (1) also in that range and (2) converge to a fixed point after iteratively applying the activation function.

You might want to have a look at the [reddit post comments](https://redd.it/6g5tg1). If you want to fully understand them, you can go ahead with the 90 page-long appendix of the [arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02515.pdf).

They got a lot of attention when they were presented, but I think they have not delivered up to the expectations, as no one seems to be talking about them lately *on the internet*.

Comment: It was published six months after the edition of my textbook. The importance to follow the news ! Thanks for the details. Is there a reason why "no one seems to be talking about them" ?

Comment: I don't know whether there are technical reasons or not, but maybe people is getting skeptical due to the "[grad student descent](https://redd.it/6hso7g)" practices lately, which makes it more difficult to get adoption unless spectacular and consistent SOTA results.

Comment: My experience with `elu` confirms your last statement: its performance is very much like `relu`, not much better or worse, but slower.

Comment: I missed your answer @ncasas, thanks I'll check that out.